# cannot find value by attribute name for element in xml parsed with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have the following XML:

```
<cpe-list>  
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:0.7">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 0.7</title>
    <meta:item-metadata nvd-id="121218" status="DRAFT" modification-date="2010-12-14T19:38:32.197Z"/>
  </cpe-item>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.2.5">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.2.5</title>
    <meta:item-metadata nvd-id="121219" status="DRAFT" modification-date="2010-12-14T19:38:32.240Z"/>
  </cpe-item>
    <cpe-item name="cpe:/h:cisco:ips_4240">
    <title xml:lang="ja-JP">JAPAN IPS 4240 Sensor</title>
    <title xml:lang="en-US">EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor</title>
    <meta:item-metadata nvd-id="138255" status="DRAFT" modification-date="2011-01-12T14:36:11.990Z"/>
  </cpe-item>
</cpe-list>
```

I need to save values of 'title' fields with only attributes lang=en-US. So I'm trying to get "EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor" with the following:

```
doc.search("//title[@lang='en-US']")
```

which returns

```
 => []
```

Please, advise how to properly get values of these fields.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute is namespaced (it's `xml:lang`, not just `lang`), so you need to include the namespace in your search:

```
doc.search("//title[@xml:lang='en-US']")
```

I just gave this a try locally and it returns all three `<title xml:lang="en-US">` elements. To get the text of each, just call `text` on each, or use `map`:

```
doc.search("//title[@xml:lang='en-US']").map(&:text)
# => [ "1024cms.org 1024 CMS 0.7",
#      "1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.2.5",
#      "EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nokogiri supports CSS selectors, so I'd do it like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<cpe-list>  
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:0.7">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 0.7</title>
    <meta:item-metadata nvd-id="121218" status="DRAFT" modification-date="2010-12-14T19:38:32.197Z"/>
  </cpe-item>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.2.5">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.2.5</title>
    <meta:item-metadata nvd-id="121219" status="DRAFT" modification-date="2010-12-14T19:38:32.240Z"/>
  </cpe-item>
    <cpe-item name="cpe:/h:cisco:ips_4240">
    <title xml:lang="ja-JP">JAPAN IPS 4240 Sensor</title>
    <title xml:lang="en-US">EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor</title>
    <meta:item-metadata nvd-id="138255" status="DRAFT" modification-date="2011-01-12T14:36:11.990Z"/>
  </cpe-item>
</cpe-list>
'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.at('title:nth-of-type(2)').to_xml # => "<title xml:lang=\"en-US\">EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor</title>"
```

CSS results in a pretty clear selector. Alternately, XPath could do it like:

```
doc.at('//title[2]').to_xml # => "<title xml:lang=\"en-US\">EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor</title>"
```

In either case, use `text` to get at the embedded/child Text node:

```
doc.at('title:nth-of-type(2)').text # => "EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor"
doc.at('//title[2]').text # => "EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor"
```

In either case, you can extend the selector to be more explicit using the ability of CSS and/or XPath to look at the parameters and their values if you need to, but, according to your example XML you don't.

This finds all matching `<title xml:lang="en-US">` tags' text:

```
doc.search('title[xml|lang="en-US"]').map(&:text) # => ["1024cms.org 1024 CMS 0.7", "1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.2.5", "EN Cisco IPS 4240 Sensor"]
```

The [Nokogiri "Searching an HTML / XML Document" tutorial](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) talks about dealing with namespaces in the "Namespaces" section and is important reading.